# SwiftUI - Delaying screen to avoid flicker for logged in users

Tags: firebase, swiftui

I'm using Firebase for authentication in my app. See below for code. Currently, because of how my app loads, if a user is already logged in, then what ends up happening is that they see a flicker of the `SignUpView()` before going to the `AppMainView`. I'm guessing this is because it takes time for session to load and register that the user is logged in already. How can I avoid this flicker? Thanks!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if (session.session != nil) {
                AppMainView()
            } else {
                SignUpView()

            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: getUser)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a `loggedIn` property in your `ObservableObject` object:

```
class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loggedIn: Bool? = nil
    ...
}
```

and present views basing on the value of the `loggedIn` variable:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore

    var body: some View {
        content
            .onAppear(perform: getUser)
    }

    var content: AnyView {
        switch session.loggedIn {
        case true:
            // User is loggeed in
            return AnyView(AppMainView())
        case false:
            // User is not loggeed in
            return AnyView(SignUpView())
        default:
            // Session not loaded
            return AnyView(LoadingView())
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, in the `SessionStore` you need to set `loggedIn` when the store finishes loading.